# bitrix настройка многоуровневого меню

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, битрикс, dropdown

Всем привет! прошу помочь решить проблему. Имеется двухуровневое меню реализованное как компонент битрикса, само меню работает корректно. Но есть задумка реализовать выпадение подменю после клика по соответствующему элементу главного меню. Для этого использую bootstrap 5.3.2 + jquery 3.6.0. Сразу скажу, что бутстрап подключен как bootstrap.bundle, т.е дело не в Popper.js. Далее идет код шаблона меню:

```
<ul class="menu_list d-none d-md-flex">
            <?php foreach ($arResult as $key => $item): ?>
                <li class="menu_list_element dropdown">
                        <?php if (!empty($item['subitem'])): ?>
                            <a class="menu_list_element_link dropdown-toggle" href="<?=$item['LINK']?>" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"
                             >
                        <?=$item['TEXT']?></a >

                        <?php else: ?>
                            <a class="menu_list_element_link 
                            <?= $item['SELECTED'] ? 'menu_list_element_link_selected' : ''?>"
                            <? /* array_key_last($arResult) === $key ? 'role="top_ticket_btn"' : '' */ ?> 
                            href="<?=$item['LINK']?>">
                        <?=$item['TEXT']?></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </a>
                    <?php if (!empty($item['subitem'])): ?>
                        <?php if ($item['SELECTED']): ?>
                            <ul class="menu_subitem_list dropdown-menu">
                                <? foreach ($item['subitem'] as $subItem): ?>
                                    <li class="menu_subitem_element">
                                        <a class="menu_subitem_element_link dropdown-item" href="<?= $subItem['LINK']?>"><?= $subItem['TEXT']?></a>
                                    </li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?> 
                    <?php endif; ?> 
                </li>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
```

и, собственно, сами ошибки:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
```

и

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /exhibitors/
```

притом пробовал сделать дропдавн на отдельной тестовой странице, в отрыве от компонента, все работает прекрасно...
Буду признателен за любую помощь или совет, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Судя по тому, что "classList" и "/exhibitors/" не встречаются в приведённом тексте, ошибка не в нём. Вероятнее всего ошибка происходит в скриптах вне данного блока, из-за чего инициализация страницы прерывается, и как результат - не работает выпадающее меню.